# in a loop: skip a certain type of error (R)

Tags: r, loops, error-handling, skip

I am using a code from:
https://www.r-bloggers.com/htmltotext-extracting-text-from-html-via-xpath/
the cose is on github:

https://github.com/tonybreyal/Blog-Reference-Functions/blob/master/R/htmlToText/htmlToText.R

It creates a command that extracts text from html:

```
htmlToText
```

I have a loop as below:

```
for(i in 1:10000){
input <- URL[i]
txt <- htmlToText(input)
write.table(txt, file = paste0(URL[i], ".txt", sep=""))
}
```

I want ito to go to next i when it gets the following error:

```
Error in function (type, msg, asError = TRUE)  :    "Could not resolve host: NA"
```

Is there a way to do that?
It may help many others using this code
Thank you

Comment: add `if(is.na(input)) next` before `read_html` ?

Comment: How is this question different from your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51296838/error-in-a-loop-in-htmltotext) which you deleted? Again, you do not provide enough details. Where does `read_html` come from? Google tells me that `rvest` and `textreadr` both have a `read_html` function.

Comment: What about when it gets a different error? Should it continue or should it stop?

Comment: I tried the following and it did not work: status <- tryCatch(
  getURL(input, ssl.verifypeer=FALSE, useragent="R"),
  error = function(e) e
)

if(inherits(status,  "error")) next
}

Comment: this is the only type of error that I get each time.

Comment: @userR It's hard to help without a self-contained minimal & reproducible example. The code you give in your comment is completely different from the code in your original post. You must take some time [editing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51316171/edit) your question to include necessary details. Don't put code in comments, comments are transient.

Comment: @chinsoon12: it worked!!!

Comment: @Maurits Evers: I changed the question because the function I was using was not from a package

Comment: @userR That still does not clarify where `read_html` comes from.

Comment: @MauritsEvers: I edited the post. Wait a minute before giving a minus.

Comment: @userR Ok thanks & I removed my down-vote. For the record, I had asked you to provide details in my first comment nearly an hour ago. Anyway, I take it chinsoon12's answer solved your issue?

Comment: @MauritsEvers Yes that one worked. I had NAs in the URLs.

Answer (score 0):

For future posts, please review how to provide a [minimal reproducible example/attempt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example); this includes clearly stating which packages you have used.

Here I assume that you are using `read_html` from `rvest`.

You could use `tryCatch` to avoid exiting from your loop. I also would replace the `for` loop with `lapply`.

Here is an example

```
library(rvest)
URL <- c("http://asd", "http://had.co.nz");
lst <- lapply(URL, function(ss)
    result <- tryCatch(
        read_html(ss),
        error = function(e) {
            print(sprintf("Could not resolve host: %s", ss));
            return(NULL);
        }
    ))
#[1] "Could not resolve host: http://asd"

lst;
#[[1]]
#NULL
#
#[[2]]
#{xml_document}
#<html lang="en">
#[1] <head>\n<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8 ...
#[2] <body id="page-top" class="index">\n\n<!-- Navigation -->\n<nav class="na ...
```

Comment: Thank you! I will use the lapply suggestion!